# Limit expression not evaluating

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have encountered an expression that doesn't evaluate when I try to take a limit.

For example, I am doing the following integral:

```
integral = 
  Integrate[
    1 - 
       Cos[4 ArcTan[-Exp[x - z] - Exp[-x + dp - z]]] 
         Cos[4 ArcTan[-Exp[x - z] - Exp[-x - z]]],
    x];
result = Limit[integral /. x -> Log[y], y -> ∞] - integral /. x -> -z
```

I get a large output as a result and I want to take the limit of `integral` as $z\rightarrow \infty$. I tried using something like the following, hoping that it would be more efficient, but it doesn't work.

```
lim = Limit[result /. z -> Log[zz], zz -> ∞]
```

Do you know a smart way to take the large $z$ limit in this case? Or in general, when one encounters such difficulties?

Comment: Timing out? Are you using a cloud-based version of Mathematica? Please explain.

Comment: by timing out, I just meant that Mathematica returns the input back as output and is unable to solve the limit. Is there a better way to say what I meant?

Comment: Yes, you should say the expression is not evaluating. That is very different than timing out.